# How to walk along all points on a line in python

Tags: python, gradient, minimization

I have a function which has a line of zeros. (Imagine say f(x)=(sin(x)/x)^2), I don't know where the line is or what shape it takes, but I can trivially find a point on the line by minimizing f(x); once I've found one point on the line of zeros, I want to map out the line by making small steps, until I get to the end of the line, or back to the start:

```
from numpy import sin
from math import pi

def f(x,y):
    r=(x**2+y**2)**0.5
    return (sin(r)/r)**2

x0=pi
y0=0
```

Now how do I trace the line of x,y that corresponds to f(x,y)=0 (in this case a circle, radius pi, but in my case the shape and position is not analytic)?

Comment: You might get some good answers here, but I would suggest also asking your question on http://math.stackexchange.com/